# How to find out which variable of a tuple was updated at willSet / didSet?

Tags: swift, tuples

How to find out which variable of a tuple was updated at willSet / didSet?

```
var myTuple: (a: Int, b: Int) {
   didSet {
      // Which one was set, a or b?
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you would get the updated values with `willSet` and access the content with the tuple's properties bridged to `newValue` (`.a` and `.b`):

```
var myTuple: (a: Int, b: Int) {
    willSet {
        print(newValue.a)
        print(newValue.b)
    }
}
```

and you can compare the values like this for example:

```
var myTuple: (a: Int, b: Int) {
    willSet {
        if newValue.a != myTuple.a {
            print(".a changed")
        }
        if newValue.b != myTuple.b {
            print(".b changed")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check oldValue like this

```
    var myTouple: (a: Int, b: Int) {
   didSet {
      print(oldValue.a)
      print(oldValue.b)
   }
}
```

and compare them. If you set only a single value of the touple, like

```
myTouple.a = 5
```

It's as if you set all, with the rest getting their old values as if you wrote

```
myTouple = (5, myTouple.b)
```